# Uploading multiple .txt files at once on MATLAB GUI

Tags: matlab, matlab-gui

I would like some guidance on how to import multiple .txt files containing data seperated by comma on a MATLAB GUI. Once the files are uploaded, I have a function that will manipulate all the data from each .txt file.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm assuming you're using the word "upload" wrongly here, and you're basically trying to "import" the data on the matlab workspace, right? If it's a standard `.csv` file you could try `csvread` (type `help csvread` to see the syntax and examples). If it's a more complicated file, then it depends on the file. As for how to select the files, you can try `uigetfile` for manual selecting, or if you want to select them in a for loop, you could try constructing the filenames using `sprintf` and `fullfile` to generate proper filenames.

Comment: Do you already have a GUI? Do you want the user to select many files at once? Do you want them to select one by one and then you put the names and separate by comma?

Comment: Mark, are you still working on this or did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to import multiple files is to:

- Use the file importer GUI in matlab and generate a script after you
  selected your preferred parameters
- Generate a script (there is a button to generate a script in the importer)
- Modify the script with a for loop to load multiple files and save them in a variable (a cell array can handle different sizes of data in each file)

Answer (score 0):

Try [`uigetfile`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uigetfile.html) to launch a dialog for loading files.  Set `'MultiSelect'` to `'on'` in order to select multiple files at once.

Here's an example call:

```
[filenames, pathname] = uigetfile({'*.txt; *.csv','Comma separated values';...
           '*.*','All files'},'Select files','MultiSelect','on');
```

You will need to check if the user actually selected a file or if they canceled.

If I understand your question correctly, you have a GUI already.  In this case you just need to add the above call to your designated callback function (i.e. whatever you click to invoke this file load interface).